# how to select image using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my html:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="myimg.png" alt="this image need to select"/>
    <div  class="some">
        <img src="another.png" alt="this is not need  to select"/>
    </div>   
</div>
```

I want to select all image which are inside id `content` but not which are inside the `div` or `span` of `content` div i.e. select all image directly inside the `content` div and not the ones that are inside the `div` or `span` of content div.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `>` to select direct/immediate children of the div like this:

```
#content > img{
  // target direct children
}
```

### [Check out the demo here](http://jsbin.com/ufowa4) (the desired image is given blue border)

**More Info:**

- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200510/css_21_selectors_part_2/

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but this should work -> `div#content > img`

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
#content > img {

}
```